Can't annotate QGIS 3.40
I've just installed QGIS 3.40, and the annotation changes have me baffled. I can no longer hit the button, click on a spot, double click on the balloon and fill it in as needed. I can fill in the rectangle, sort of, but then can't change it or create a tail/pointer as before. What am I missing?

Hey welcome to GIS StackExchange. There are a lot of annotation changes in QGIS 3.40: https://www.qgis.org/project/visual-changelogs/visualchangelog340/#annotations It would be really useful if you added some images on what you mean. What was it like before and what it the issue now.

Well, this might depend on various factors like do you have a MacBook. In MacBook the best QGIS version to work with would be long term version, the other QGIS versions don't run properly on Mac. If you have a PC and Windows then I don't know the reason but try restarting the app, deleting and downloading again after restarting your device.
